# Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using generation folder after Android Annotations

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I can't run my project after adding the @EActivity Annotation to my class.

This is my Gradle Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my Gradle Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def AAVersion = '4.2.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tasks"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

After I added the Android Annotations in my Gradle I noticed that my AndroidMannifest didn't get automatically modified (Missing the _ in the activity), and when I add that manually it gets highlighted in red.

If I run the project normally (Without modifying the AndroidMannifest or changing the class to Annotations) it will run normally.

If I add the annotations and modify the Manifest I'll receive the error:

> error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation
>   folder
>   [C:\Users\Asusc\AndroidStudioProjects\Tasks\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug])

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should update to AndroidAnnotations 4.6.0 . This version has Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.+ support.

Comment: It worked out! I upgraded the AAVersion for 4.6.0 and removed the line
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

Thank you!!

Comment: didn't worked in my case. AAVersion is 4.6.0 and gradle is 3.5.2.

Comment: @NirojShr Please try to downgrade the Gradle version to 3.4.1.

Comment: I was using AA 4.6.0 and gradle 3.5.3. even though I find it ridiculous that I had to downgrade back to such an older version, gradle 3.4.1 indeed worked.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, adding this to build.gradle fixed it:

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["androidManifestFile": "$projectDir/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downgrading to gradle 3.4.1 wasn't an option I wanted to consider and this solution came through for me. Thanks

Comment: Especially when your project contains splits such as flavours, AA has problem to get with this and puting path to the manifest file arbitrally fixes the problem. See more: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2034

Answer (score 4):

If you are using AndroidAnnotations 4.6.0 with Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.+, you can downgrade the Android Gradle Plugin version to 3.4.1 to fix.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```